# Create materialised view without primary key column

Tags: sql, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Is it possible to create materialised view without using one of the primary key.

**Use Case:-**
I have a table with two primary keys, user_id and app_id, I want to create view to fetch data on the basis of app_id regardless of user_id. I am trying to create materialised view but Cassandra is not allowing me to do so if I keep only one primary key.

***I know the fact that, I can use "allow filtering" but this will not give 100% accuracy in data.***

Comment: Your table has one primary key. The primary key has two columns.

Answer (score 1):

In Cassandra, materialized view should always include all existing primary key components, but they could be in the different order.  So in this case, you can create MV with primary key of `app_id`, `user_id`, but this may lead to big partitions if you have very popular application.

But I suggest just to create a second table with necessary primary key, and populate it from your application - it could be even more performant than having materialized view, because it needs to read data from disk every time you insert/update/delete record in the main table. Plus, take into account that materialized views in Cassandra are experimental feature, and have quite a lot of problems.

Comment: Second table is not a solution for older data, i need to maintain older data.

Comment: Create second table and populate it with old data... for example with Spark.

Comment: This is not a good solution, just for a report i will duplicate data, your solution is good but not the exact I am looking for. thanks :)

Comment: If it is just for report (you didn’t write the purpose) you have other ways, like, Spark, etc.